# Pass Variable From JavaScript To External PHP File

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file that runs a sql server parameter query.  I need to pass the hiredate to my php file but it is not being passed in.  I am sure the syntax is the issue here, but not sure what to alter to for it to work ->

```
<input type="date" name="inputdate" />

<script>
  var inputdate = document.getElementById("inputdate")
  var UrlToSend="Helper.Php"
  xmlhttp.open("GET", UrlToSend+'hiredate'=+inputdate, false);
</script>
```

Comment: You'll have to clarify what your `UrlToSend` variable is. Also, `hiredate=` should be in a string like `urlToSend + 'hiredate=' + inputDate`. And be careful with encoding the date as a string — is this a typed string, or an integer, what's the expected url. Question is unclear.

Comment: I am wanting to pass the value selected from inputdate into my Helper.php file to use as the parameter for the query stored the helper.php.  Does that help?

Comment: Log `UrlToSend+'hiredate'=+inputdate` to console or output it in an alert, and think about whether that address makes any sense.

Comment: why are you naming your php files Php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls change 
`<input type="date" name="inputdate" />`
to 
`<input type="date" id="inputdate" />`

and try

The getElementById() method returns the element that has the ID attribute with the specified value

If you want to use the val, pls use .value

so 
`var inputdate = document.getElementById("inputdate")` 
to be changed to

`var inputdate = document.getElementById("inputdate").value;`

[Update]

Yes, a ? is missed. ? is used to pass GET query string parameter values. The general syntax of query parameter is URL?param1=value1&param2=value2 for 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

getElementById gets the element by its id, try adding the id attribute to your input;

```
<input type="date" name="inputdate" id="inputdate" />
```

Comment: Does hiredate need to be surrounded by single quotes?

Comment: Yes, as long as it´s a string and not a variable

Comment: But you may want to add a questionmark like so; xmlhttp.open("GET", UrlToSend+'?hiredate'=+inputdate, false);

Comment: and my php file will be able to interpret the values/variables if I add in a ? mark

Comment: Yes, if you don´t have a questionmark then php interprets it as part of the URL. You should be able to get the variable in your PHP file by writing: $_GET['hiredate']

Answer (score 0):

Try this (jquery) :

```
<input type="date" name="inputdate" id="indutdate" />

<script>
  var inputdate = $("#inputdate").val() ; 
... 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your code you are using simple ajax which is very tedious it's you use jQuery Ajax function which will be a lot more simple and the url you are making is wrong and contains syntax error.

xmlhttp.open("GET", UrlToSend+"?hiredate="+inputdate, false);

It will be like this and you need to create the xmlhttp object first.

In server side coding you will need to $_GET['hiredate'] so that you will get the value of hiredate variable

Comment: I just told you a better way. I am not forcing you to use it. and also I have mentioned the error in the question which was the syntax error